# Calculated field formula

Tags: splist

When I tried this, it didn't work...

=IF([Circuit Type]="ISDN",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.81) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.42) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.84),IF([Circuit Type]="56",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.45) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 1.85) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.3) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.77),IF([Circuit Type]="19.2",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 1.73) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 1.31) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 0.96) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.59),IF([Circuit Type]="DDS T.R",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 1.91) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 1.46) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.08) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.64),IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL",(([len_26] + [dlen_26]) * 3.88 + (([len_24] +[dlen_24]) * 2.84) + (([len_22] + [dlen_22]) * 2.18) + (([len_19] + [dlen_19]) * 1.5) + (([f1_bt + f2_bt]) * 3) + [nogachf1] + [nogachf2],)))))

is it because of my ended parentheses count isn't correct?
Thank you very much I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there were multiple issues. Below is the correct formula

```
=IF([Circuit Type]="ISDN",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.81) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 2.03) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.42) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.84),IF([Circuit Type]="56",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 2.45) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 1.85) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.3) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.77),IF([Circuit Type]="19.2",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 1.73) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 1.31) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 0.96) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.59),IF([Circuit Type]="DDS T.R",(([len_26] + [bt_26] + [dlen_26] + [dbt_26]) * 1.91) + (([len_24] + [bt_24] + [dlen_24] + [dbt_24]) * 1.46) + (([len_22] + [bt_22] + [dlen_22] + [dbt_22]) * 1.08) + (([len_19] + [bt_19] + [dlen_19] + [dbt_19]) * 0.64),IF([Circuit Type]="HDSL",(([len_26] + [dlen_26]) * 3.88 + (([len_24] +[dlen_24]) * 2.84) + (([len_22] + [dlen_22]) * 2.18) + (([len_19] + [dlen_19]) * 1.5) + (([f1_bt + f2_bt]) * 3) + [nogachf1] + [nogachf2]),0)))))
```